# モダンな mail コマンドはあるか

Tags: unix, mail

サーバー上で自分(ログインユーザー)当てに送られたメールを確認するためには、 `mail` や `mailx` コマンドを使うと思いますが、これは、使い勝手はそんなによくないな、と思っています。(矢印キーすら使えない、など)

`top` コマンドに対して `htop` コマンドがあるように、メールの確認をよりやりやすく実行するためのコマンドラインツールなどはないでしょうか？

Answer (score 2, accepted):

気になったので調べてみたら、[Mutt](http://www.mutt.org/) というテキストベースのメールクライアントがありました。
キーバインドでの操作やキーボードマクロ、スレッド表示や正規表現による検索などをサポートしているようです。

カスタマイズ項目が多いので、Vimなどと同じようにパワーユーザー向けな印象です。

[image]

Comment: muttは自分も利用していましたが、2002年から現在まで開発が続けられていたのですね。